# How to pass an event handler callback to a child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use javascript's array.map to generate a list of icons some of which are links to external sights, and some of which toggle certain booleans on and off.

So far, my state which contains the array I'm mapping has js objects which in turn have functions.

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    appLinks: [
        {
          img: "../icons/twitter.svg",
          hoverState: "",
          funcionality: window.open("https://twitter.com/kaios?lang=en")
        },
        {
          img: "../icons/cart.svg",
          hoverState: "",
          funcionality: (this.toggleWindow)
        },
      ]

  render() {
    return (
          <AppBar
            appLinks={this.state.appLinks}
            update={this.updateAppBar.bind(this)}
          />
    );
  }
```

That's my parent class, containing an array of of links I want to create.

```
const appBar = props => {
  return (
    <div className="appBar" onMouseLeave={() => props.update(20)}>
      {props.appLinks.map((appLink, index) => {
        return (
          <div
            key={index}
            className={"app_icon " + appLink.hoverState}
            onClick={appLink.functionality}
            onMouseOver={() => props.update(index)}
          >
            <img src={appLink.img} />
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

There's my presentation class.

I want the several link components in my array to open up an external link and I want the other divs to trigger a function in the parent function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! 
Thanks!

Comment: You're almost there. The `funcionality` prop should look like `funcionality: () => {...stuff}`

Comment: Can you specify the error or the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide a function instead of an expression for your `functionality prop` and correct the typo for `functionality` in the appLinks array. Your array would look like

```
appLinks: [
        {
          img: "../icons/twitter.svg",
          hoverState: "",
          functionality: () => window.open("https://twitter.com/kaios?lang=en")
        },
        {
          img: "../icons/cart.svg",
          hoverState: "",
          functionality: this.toggleWindow
        },
      ]
```